# Convert Linq IQueryable<string> to Linq IQueryable<Custom Type>

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-6, linq-to-entities

I am new to using Linq Queries and I am trying to convert an IQueryable to a custom type  but I am running into issues. See the code below; I’ve tried to add `.ToList<>()` I’ve tried to use `.Cast<>()` and nothing works. Any insight would be great.

> Error: Cannot implicitly convert type `'System.Linq.IQueryable<string>'`
>   to `'System.Linq.IQueryable<eSTIP.Models.User>'`. An explicit conversion
>   exists (are you missing a cast?)

```
private static List<UserViewModel> _allBCCUsers = null;
public static List<UserViewModel> AllBCCUsers
{
    get
    {
        if (_allBCCUsers == null)
        {
            eSTIPContext ctx = new eSTIPContext();
            IQueryable<User> users = from u in ctx.BBCRecipient select u.Email; //Error On this line

            _allBCCUsers = new List<UserViewModel>();
            foreach (User u in users)
                _allBCCUsers.Add(new UserViewModel(u));

        }
        return _allBCCUsers;
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably, you want so "select u", if u is a user. Or at the beginn of the line you want an IQueryable<string>, if you want  a list of emails. But your variable decleration and what you select from the database just don't much.

Comment: @Holger yes I want to return a list of email addresses. I just took over thos project so I am getting used to the code. I actually dont want to check of the email so tied to a user as these addresses are used to include names on am email list

Comment: I'm not sure if you understood my answer. Do you know what to do now ? change "u.email" to "u" and everything is fine. you can also have a list of string, but than you cannot fill you allBCCUsers list.

Comment: @Holger if I change u.email to u how will i ensure i am grabbing just the email address

Comment: No, you grab the entire user and make your code work, if you only want the e-mail, you have to change your entire method. The UserViewModel stores as User, the return value of the method is a List of UserViewModel, etc. The method is not made just to return a list of strings.

Comment: @Holger so if I change the type to string I should be fine and I can pass data to a partial view using iemumerable<string>

Comment: @jamHud Does `User` class has `Email`  property?

Answer (score 0):

The compiler explains exactly what is happening in your code.

With `from u in ctx.BBCRecipient select u.Email` you are selecting only the `Email` property from `u` (users?) wich is a **string** and you are trying to store it in a IQueryable of type **User**.

Now you have two options: change your select to `select u` (like @Holger said) or change to `IQueryable<string>` but in this case you need more dramatic changes in your after code.

Comment: When you say more dramatic code changes what are you referring to? As I said I'm new so explanations are my best friend right now.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand from your question, you want to return List of `UserViewModel` that contains `User`'s those have `Email`.

To do so you can select directly `List<UserViewModel>` from LINQ without any iteration need:

```
private static List<UserViewModel> _allBCCUsers = null;
public static List<UserViewModel> AllBCCUsers
{
    get
    {
        if (_allBCCUsers == null)
        {
            eSTIPContext ctx = new eSTIPContext();
            _allBCCUsers = (from u in ctx.BBCRecipient select new UserViewModel(new User() { Email = u.Email })).ToList();

        }
        return _allBCCUsers;
    }
}
```